# asp:textbox readonly

Tags: asp.net, textbox

In asp file I have two asp:textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue" runat="server" Width="100px"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue2" runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

then I set the value via javascript getting

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue" runat="server" Width="100px" value="aaa"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue2" runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true" value="bbb"/>
```

but when refresh the webpage finally get

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue" runat="server" Width="100px" value="aaa"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue2" runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

Why the value bbb is "lost"? How can I avoid this?

Comment: how can u set value to read only textbox

Comment: With javascript. A tipical example is a Calendar + Input text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"bbb" is being posted back, but .NET will not populate a read-only textbox from postback data.  You can manually populate the text box by grabbing the form data yourself from the `Page_Load()` method as follows:

`textValue2.Text = Request.Form[textValue2.UniqueID];`

Answer (score 17):

Remove the server side attribute - ReadOnly - from the TextBox and set the HTML attribute from the code. You will be able to access the value then in post back:

```
textValue2.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textValue2" runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true"/>
```

You are missing a quotation mark before 'true', it might cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of readonly, set your value to the textbox and then disable it.