# asp.net,c#.net Read Only Field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox.Texbox is readonly. And on Page_Load the Texbox automaticlly displayed
with a value from the data base.i have a 'if' loop for check the text box value is null
or not.But i cant retrive the textbox value.What may be the reason for that?
my web page code is

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "text1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Visible="False">
</asp:DropDownList>`
```

code behind

```
if (text1.Text == "")
{
    DropDownList1.Visible = true;
}
```

but  DropDownList1 is not displayed

Comment: what  do you mean when u say  i cant retrive the value? is it throwing any error?is it empty or null?

Comment: imean i want to check the if(textbox.text=="").but cant get the textbox value

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID = "text1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Your text box appears to be called `text1` not `textbox`

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp:textbox readonly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870183/asptextbox-readonly)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you cannot post back the values which are either readonly or enabled = false. You have to find out some other way to post them to server.

Comment: I got a solution for this problem. What you can do is... You can hidden fields and when you press the submit button, first of all copy the text fields which are readonly into that hidden fields via javascript and then on server use that hidden values instead of the text box. this worked for me pretty well !!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to place a hidden input next to textbox with runat attribute set to "server" and check input's value after postback (of course you will have to fill the input with the same value as textbox). Doesn't seem a beautiful decision for me, but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your database may contain space values. 
So you cant compare " " with ""
You just try to trim the text box value and then try to compare.